# Adjusting plane thickness based on amplitude of mapped UV image

Tags: modifiers, uv-image-editor, subdivision-surface

I have a subdivided plane with a number of cells removed. The final product, after removing cells, is shown below: [image: face]

Even though the contrast is low, is there a way for me to add a thickness to the plane based on the value of the existing pixels? For example, I'd like the brighter pixels to be taller than the dark pixels.

I feel like I've seen a method of doing this before when making grass, but I cannot find it again. So far, I've played around with the "Solidify" modifier on the plane, to no avail. I am using Blender 2.79.0

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this is done with the Displacement modifier. Selecting all of the pixels and assigning them to a group, I can complete the Displacement modifier  inputs: 
[image]

Resulting in this:

[image]